# Is there an R function for conditional joins?

Tags: r, join, conditional-statements, vlookup

I've tried merge, left_join, and SQL and these are good for exact matches. How do I do a conditional join in R using the example below? It's easy in Excel when I use vlookup but I want to keep all my data manipulation in R.

[Image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agfAj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R this isn't really a join, it's more of an interval look up. You can do this somewhat easily with `cut()` For example

```
cut(Students$Mark, c(Grades_table$Mark, 100), Grades_table$Grade)
# [1] D    C    B    A    Fail C    A+  
# Levels: Fail E D C B A A+
```

Comment: I created an example to put this great solution into context. [link](https://github.com/ahooty/random-html/blob/master/rLookup)

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `findInterval`

```
Grades_table$Grade[findInterval(Students$Mark, Grades_table$Mark)]
#[1] D    C    B    A    Fail C    A+
```